# Extending TypeScript Map to restrict data type

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance

I am trying to create a class `FooMap` that extends the default TypeScript `Map` class by restricting the type of parameters it accepts. The reason I am extending the `Map` class is because I want to write methods for that class that I will be accessing from different files.

The default Map class is `Map<any,any>`, however the `FooMap` class would be similar to a `Map<number,Foo>` using the built-in `number` type and user-defined `Foo` type. The `FooMap` would only accept these key/value pairs.

My attempt to to this was by passing a map in the constructor but I feel like there is a better way to do this.

```
// Say Foo class is defined as    
export class Foo {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Now, the `FooMap` class would be:

```
export class FooMap extends Map{
    constructor(otherMap : Map<number,Foo>){
        super(otherMap);
    }
}
```

But this does not work since `super()` only accepts an iterable, so there must be a better way to extend the `Map` class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make your class extending a fully instantiated generic `Map` as well:

```
export class FooMap extends Map<number, Foo> {
```

but to make it work you should target `es6` (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10853)

Answer (score 1):

I am will extend zerkms' answer here with a succinct example:

**tl;dr**

1. Create new class `FooMap` implementing `Map<number, Foo>`
2. Add private inner `Map<number, Foo>`
3. Expose all the functionality of the `Map` class

3a. Use IDE to declare all the interface functions of `Map`

3b. For each function return the inner Map's same function call

```
class OptionalMap <K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    // Inner map
    private _innerMap: Map<K, V>;

    constructor(optionalFunctions: { fnName: string, fn: (value: V, ...args) => void }[]) {
        this._innerMap = new Map<K, V>();
        
        // My additional functionality to the standard Map. Note functionality is applied to this class not the inner Map
        if(optionalFunctions) {
            for (let optionalFunction of optionalFunctions) {
                if(this[optionalFunction.fnName]) {
                    throw new Error(`Reserved function name: ${optionalFunction.fnName}`);
                } else {
                    this[optionalFunction.fnName] = (key, ...args) => {
                        if(this.has(key)) {
                            optionalFunction.fn(this.get(key), ...args);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Exposing all the inner map's inherit functions here in implementing the interface 

    clear(): void {
        return this._innerMap.clear();
    }
    delete(key: K): boolean {
        return this._innerMap.delete(key);
    }
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void {
        return this._innerMap.forEach(callbackfn, thisArg);
    }
    get(key: K): V {
        return this._innerMap.get(key);
    }
    has(key: K): boolean {
        return this._innerMap.has(key);
    }
    set(key: K, value: V): this {
        this._innerMap.set(key, value);
        return this;
    }
    size: number;
    entries(): IterableIterator<[K, V]> {
        return this._innerMap.entries();
    }
    keys(): IterableIterator<K> {
        return this._innerMap.keys();
    }
    values(): IterableIterator<V> {
        return this._innerMap.values();
    }
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[K, V]> {
        return this._innerMap.entries();
    }
    [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;

}

export default OptionalMap;
```